# Creating many new dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to create a lot of dataframes. is there any faster way where you can only specify the names of new tables and assign <- data.frame () once ?

```
results_test <- data.frame()
results_OA<- data.frame()
results_SVM <- data.frame()
results_SVM_linear <- data.frame()
results_SVM_RBF <- data.frame()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `replicate` to create a list of `n` data frames, name them using `setNames`.  Finally, with `list2env` put the list objects into e.g. the global environment.

```
df.names <- paste0("results_", c("test", "OA", "SVM", "SVM_linear", "SVM_RBF"))
df.list <- setNames(replicate(n=length(df.names)), df.names)
list2env(df.list, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

*Result:*

```
ls()
# [1] "df.list"            "results_OA"         "results_SVM"        "results_SVM_linear"
# [5] "results_SVM_RBF"    "results_test"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is using for loop, base R

```
names<-c("test", "OA", "SVM", "SVM_linear", "SVM_RBF")
for(i in 1:length(names)){
  assign(paste0("results_",names[i]),data.frame())
}
```